# Display output of bash command line on html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bash, http, websocket

I have the bash script written so that my customized commands output some data in text format. I would like to have a button on a webpage that when clicked, takes the user to another page that displays the output of the command. For a simple example, let's say the user clicks the 'pwd' button. I would like the next page to just display /usr/somedirectory or something similar.

I'm new to JavaScript and HTML but have been playing around with some HTTP GET and POST methods along with researching a bit on websockets. What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but I must give a health warning: I would be very, very careful if you're allowing user input to execute shell scripts on your computer/server, because you could quite easily create opportunities for an attacker to execute code on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to redirect the output of the bash command to a text file (ex.: command1.txt), like this:

```
pwd > /folder/command1.txt
```

and then open a new html page which will have the file command1.txt embedded on it as an object, like this:

```
<object data="/folder/command1.txt" type="text/plain"></object>
```

You could then create a new html page and .txt file for each command button you have. Also, it would be very advisable to put a "sleep" or delay of 1 second or so (depending on your configuration) to display the html page so that the system has enough time to create the command file.

Also, as discussed on the comment section of your question, be careful with what you are allowing to be run as that can create a security problem.